# Why can't we upload .pptx files to our SharePoint doucment library?

Tags: document-library

uploading other formats works fine but we get an error uploading pptx files - any suggestions?

tried through our TFS Documents interface as well as the SharePoint interface but both give errors.

Invalid look-up value.

A look-up field contains invalid data. Please check the value and try again. 
Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 
Correlation ID: d614c006-573e-4439-9a47-fe6f43045d5a 
Date and Time: 12/18/2013 10:41:31 AM

Comment: What error message is given in the ULS logs with that correlation id? Also, can you try cleaning the file properties and see if that helps? See this for reference, http://patrikluca.blogspot.com/2009/01/invalid-look-up-value-durig-upload-of.html

Comment: In Central Administration goto "Security" and check "Blocked File Types". Doesn't seem like a perfect fit for the symptom, but it's worth a check :)